# openshift metrics per namespace

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes, metrics

Hello how can i provide usage metrics like:
- cpu usage per container
- persistantVolume fill level
- network usage per container/pod

of an openshift cluster.

But individual per namespace/project only access able for the namespace owner?
Because each name space owner is responsible for its pod and has to monitor them.

I need it in prometheus exporter format.
An kube-stats-metrics pod already provides me some other informations but the usage metrics are missing.

Comment: What is your Kubernetes and OpenShift version? Are you using any monitoring tool like `Prometheus` already on the cluster?

Comment: OpenShift 3.11. Or any newer version. Yes there are severyl prometheus instances running.